# preg_match link text with less-than sign in it

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get information in DB from html files, and suddenly found that link can be like:

```
<a href="/blabla/12345678" class="someclass">channel crosstalk: <60dB</a>
```

there for my regular expression doesn't find that link:

```
preg_match_all('|<a href="/blabla/([0-9]+)"[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>|Uis',$html,$matches);
```

This is a part of big regular expression, I just simplified it for example.

Comment: What information are trying to extract from this anchor tag?  Your question is not clear about this.

Comment: what information you want to extract from this html

Comment: This regex doesn't work because there is an unaccounted for opening angle bracket in the link text. That is the OP's question. Not what to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fundamental issue with trying to regex HTML. This is not really good HTML - because contents that are not meant to be interpreted as HTML should be html entities (aka `&lte;` instead of `<`). You won't always be able to handle that though.

In your case, something like this works for regex:

```
|<a href="/blabla/([0-9]+)">.*?</a>|Uis
```

The matching group gets shifted. This also allows nested tags (like `<a><b><i></i></b></a>`).

Keep in mind that the Ungreedy tag you used means that you can be a little more lax in your regex matching. If you wanted to do this without the `U` modifier you'd maybe need to do some negative lookaheads.

```
|<a href="/blabla/([0-9]+)">(?:(?!</a>).)*</a>|is
```

Comment: Thank you. I do understand problem with wrong HTML, but i'm not author of this HTML and I have to deal with that.
Nevertheless your last expression really helped me.
I just modified it it a bit. 
|<a href="/blabla/([0-9]+)"[^>]*>((?:(?!</a>).)*)</a>|Uis

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to pull. Are you looking for the entire link? Or are you looking to grab parts from the link (hence the parenthesis)? Here is a solution for getting the individual contents in the link:

```
preg_match_all( '#<a href="/.*?/(\d+)" class="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>#i', $html, $matches);
```

The first element of matches will be the entire link, while the other elements will be the sub parts.

Or here is one for just the entire link:

```
preg_match_all( "#(<a.*>.*</a>)#i", $html, $matches );
```

Or here is a slightly modified version of yours which currently isn't matching because it's saying to match anything that is not an angle bracket inside the opening and closing A tags as its contents has an angle bracket:

```
preg_match_all( '|<a href="/blabla/([0-9]+)"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>|Uis', $html, $matches );
```

Again, not 100% sure the exact results you are looking for, but maybe this will get your going and you can make modifications as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to extract **href** and **link text**.

```
<a[^>]+?href="(.*?)"[^>]+?>(.*?)</a>
```

`Group 1`: href

`Group 2`: link text